Monopoly ultimate banking / Monopoly voice banking
I have considered buying these games but i've seen reviews about the monotony of them after a few games.
Is there any info about the technical details of these games like the microcontroller or hardware used, so i can consider dumping the firmware and modify it to change the rules for custom games.
Any hint where to find more info would be appreciated as well.
Regards.

the manufacturer has the technical documents

it would probably be easier to build your own from scratch
